# % of samples below median with mean of sampling distribution and N?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, mean

I'm working on a homework problem and am unsure if this is a trick question. My understanding of the mean of the sampling distribution (`μ_m`) is that its used when calculating z-scores and finding the probability of something happening. Could I, then, infer anything about the percentage of samples below the median given just `μ_m` and `n`?

Comment: This can be answered given only the definition of median, without any data, isn't it..?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "samples"?  Would that refer to *observations within a sample* or to *entire datasets*?

Comment: For example, if a question asks: "given a sampling distribution with μ_m = x and n = y, is it possible to find the percentage of samples that fall below the median just from these two variables?"